# Local Maximum Point and Proof

Tags: functions

> If a differentiable function f on (-∞, ∞) has a local maximum point at
>   x = 0, then f'(0) = 0 .

I wanna prove it but I couldn't. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is a local maximum, $f(x)\geq f(x\pm h)$ for all $h>0$ sufficiently
small. Then,
$$
0\leq\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}=f^{\prime}(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\leq0
$$
and hence $f^{\prime}(x)=0$.